# To get Map as result set in Spring boot JPA

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to get the SQL native query results as Map like alias name as key and column value as value in Spring boot JPA
For example:

The query `SELECT u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName from user u` returns two rows. An entity manager in JPA should returns,

```
[{
"firstName": "XXX",
"lastName": "YYY"
}, {
"firstName": "AAA",
"lastName": "BBB"
}]
```

Comment: You can create a repository extending the pojo class and formulate a query method to give you the desired output

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a repository extending the pojo class and formulate a query method to give you the desired output**

**users.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@EntityListeners(UsersEntityListener.class)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")})
public class User extends Domain implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "GENDER", nullable = false)
    private String gender;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MOBILE", nullable = false)
    private String mobile;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "URL")
    private String url;

    public User() {
    }

//*************Getters and Setters******************/
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {

     @Query("select u.firstName,u.lastName from Users u ")
        List<BuyingRequirement> find();

    }
```

now you can use this method directly as:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class xyz{

@Autowired
UserRepository ur;

 @GetMapping(value = "/user")
    public List<Users> getNameandLastName(){
        List user= ur.find();

        return user;
    }

}
```

**This will give required result list in key value pair**

Comment: I don't want to use the repository.

Comment: you have mentioned Spring boot JPA and that's how its implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl;
import java.sql.Connection;


Connection connection = entitymanager.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).connection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(procedure);`

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```